# How to install a python package without changing path environment variable?

Tags: python, cmake, path, pip, dlib

On trying to install python package `dlib` using `pip`, I encountered a runtime error namely:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
.....
.....
File "C:\Users\user-1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i8yuk2fa\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
File "C:\Users\user-1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i8yuk2fa\dlib\setup.py", line 125, in get_cmake_version
        "\n*******************************************************************\n")
RuntimeError:
*******************************************************************
CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
*******************************************************************
```

I have CMake installed on the machine but I have not added `cmake.exe`'s location to `PATH` because of certain restrictions. Is there anyway I can give location of `cmake.exe` file i.e `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin` as argument while installing via `pip` instead of changing the Path Environment Variable via Advanced System Settings on a Windows 10 OS?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have an IDE like CLion or PyCharm installed, they have an UI for installing packages in a virtual environment, which has also its own PATH environment. As a non objective side note: *I recommend against using DLib with Python, the C++ API is much richer. I'd either use DLib with C++ or a different ML library. There are several big ones out there with elaborate Python APIs.*

Comment: @nada Had to use `set` command. Thank you for your non-objective side note. Feel free to state any specific ML library suggestions for Python.

Comment: caffe, OpenCV, **TensorFlow**, MXNet, OpenNN, **scikit-learn**, Theano, Pylearn2, Pattern ... Bold ones are my personal recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the command prompt, can you set add to the PATH variable temporarily? Like:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is can I enter something like `pip install --some-option="C:/Program Files/CMake/bin" dlib --user`?

Comment: @user-D-one No. dlib's `setup.py` [calls cmake directly](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/0268e27481fd6926c01b6a789e8b8851f7b4dbbc/setup.py#L120) so it must be in the `%PATH%`, and there is no option in `pip` to set `%PATH%`.

Comment: @phd Perfect. Thank you for clarifying. Is this the go-to process - i.e. to check the `setup.py` of any package that a user wants to install in order to see where exactly the problem is occuring?

Comment: @Robin Chow Gonna mark your solution as the accepted answer. The user "phd" clarified why that's the only way.

Comment: `setup.py` is the 1st place to look for and there is also `setup.cfg`.

Comment: @phd Awesome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no way for you to do this unless you can change the path in command prompt with setx or set. If you cannot change the path with the command prompt, then there is no solution to your problem unless you can move cmake to somewhere on your path.

Comment: Accepted your and Robin's answer based on user "phd" 's clarification above. Thank you for helping.